# Hints to solve task about passing data from form to classes

Tags: c#

I have a task for which I need some hints and explanation to solve and understand it. It's about a register for customers.

A ContactForm that has relation with Contact, and Contact has a relation with Adress, Email and Phone.

The user enters information in the ContactForm and this information should then be passed and checked in the classes Adress, Email and Phone. But I guess the information must go via the Contact class. So then I create an object of Contact inside ContactForm and send the data to the constructor of Contact, but it's expected that I'm using object references in the constructor of Adress, Phone and Email that are declared in the fields of Contact. This I don't understand how it work? Perhaps the use of object reference is to avoid to send to much data to the constructor of Contact?

I'm also going to use properties to set and get the information, and same thing here, I'm expected to use references of objects.

The constructor for Contact should look like this, if I understand my instructions:

```
Contact(string firstName, string lastname, Adress adr, Phone tel, Email mail)
```

It's here that I don't understand how the data from the form should be passed when I need to use a constructor like this?

Comment: I really don't get what you mean by _"using object references in the constructor of Adress, Phone and Email that are declared in the fields of Contact. "_ Can you show some code?

Comment: Have you read and understood my post? I think the second part clearly shows how to pass Object References to your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The point of using object references in your constructor is that it's more dynamic.
Suppose i made a constructor like this :

```
public void main()
{
    var c = new Contact("europeroad",9999, "USA");
}

public Contact(string address, int zipcode, string country){
    this.Address = new Address(address,zipcode,country);
}
```

This off course would work but what happens if you add new fields? region, createdon , ...
You'd have to adjust 2 constructors and 2 constructor calls.

If you do it like you suggested with object references you'd have the following result:

```
public void main()
{
  var a = new Address();
  a.Street = "europeroad";
  a.Zipcode = 9999;
  a.Country = "USA";
  var c = new Contact(a);
}
public Contact(Address address){
    this.Address = address;
}
```

Adding a new field here would only result in changing the main method(no signature changes are needed).

Answer (score -1):

It depends on your use case, domain model which you generate it from UC and system sequence diagram.
Honestly, I can say this is very common UC and there are many solution. Based on Craig Larmans OO Analysis and Design Book:

UC:
User enters contact information.
System checks the validity of the information. (we can detail this step for any error, Now I want to explain it briefly so I wont detail it ...)
System show success message to the user.

According to them, System has  contact concept and contact contains Address  Email and Phone. Domain model has four different concepts which are Contact, Address, Email and Phone. 
According to UC and Grasp Design patterns you need to implement Controller Object to seperate UI and Bussines Logic.

Contact/Some kind of result indications ContactController(user, address information, Phone information)

Because contact  can be expressed  by the information coming from Controller, creating Contact object is more understandable. 
It's my opinion, Design is of more importance than how much data it comsumes. And  honestly I can say if your object comsumes so much data you have design problem:)